# Linear Regression in groups / Multivariate regression

Tags: regression, linear

I try to do a linear regression of 84 patients, 1 numeric variable =threshold, 1 nominal variable=Group for prediction of the target numeric variable = dist.

On the multivariate linear regression: threshold is statistical significant, and group isn't.
However, when I split the data for the 2 different groups which Group is made of and running the linear regression just for threshold and dist:

- Group1 -threshold remains significant
- Group 2 - threshold is not significant.

I wonder - in that case why wasn't it seen in the multivariate linear regression? which way is the "right" way to conclude from this experiment?

Comment: Splitting the data into two groups and running two analyses is similar to including an interaction between threshold and group in your full dataset model. Your original model is equivalent to splitting the data into two groups, but forcing the coefficient of threshold and residual variance to be the same in both models. Additionally, multivariate usually refers to multiple response variables, not multiple predictors. Just "linear regression" is fine in your case.

Comment: I partly understand. I didn't understand why the coefficient of groups isn't  significant...